# How to create a Customized Drop Down Menu Similar to the chrome bookmarks bar?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to create a drop down menu which can contain some bookmarks within a main div. if the user adds more bookmarks and the bookmarks cant be contained within the main div they will be hidden in the drop down menu. the user can then hover on a arrow and the hidden menu drops showing the rest of the bookmarks.

[image]

I will need to check if the next bookmark can be added to the main div and based on that( if the main div is out of space) append the next bookmark to the dropdown menu.

If there are any similar tutorials on the web please let me know , any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create it as a single unordered list.

To check how many li's fit in:

```
noOfLi = width of ul / width of li

$(ul.normal).width() to get width of ul and same function for li
```

check if

```
noOfLi > $('ul.normal li').length //if not no problem yyay
```

Take a copy of all li's for processing.

```
var lis = $('ul.normal li').clone(); //now you have an array of li nodes
```

Split it into two parts, one part for regular ul, one part for drop down.

```
normalLis = lis.slice( 0, noOfLi - 1 );
dropdownLi = lis.slice( noOfLi, lis.length );
```

Now put normalLis into normal ul, dropdown lis to dropdown ul

```
$('ul.normal').html(normalLis)
$('ul.dropdown').html(dropdownLis)
```

You can also activate more link if lis overflow, and add hover event on that to show dropdown on hover.

All above code is for illustration purpose only, dont copy paste.